# Can't install python cryptography on Cygwin

Tags: python, pip, cygwin

I have installed python38-cryptogrpahy package v.3.3.2-1 thru cygwin but when I try to install fabric via pip - it tries to build it and fails with next error:

```
$ pip install -r ./requirements.txt
Collecting fabric3
  Using cached Fabric3-1.14.post1-py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)
Collecting paramiko<3.0,>=2.0
  Using cached paramiko-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (206 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from fabric3->-r ./requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.16.0)
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1
  Using cached PyNaCl-1.4.0-cp38-cp38-cygwin_3_3_3_x86_64.whl
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.3
  Using cached bcrypt-3.2.0-cp38-cp38-cygwin_3_3_3_x86_64.whl
Collecting cryptography>=2.5
  Using cached cryptography-36.0.1.tar.gz (572 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting cffi>=1.1
  Using cached cffi-1.15.0-cp38-cp38-cygwin_3_3_3_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko<3.0,>=2.0->fabric3->-r ./requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Building wheel for cryptography (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/dnester/repo/vastuf_server_common/containers/smart_home/rvalarm/env/bin/python /home/dnester/repo/vastuf_server_common/containers/smart_home/rvalarm/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpojt6ejpa
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cxk1g2b2/cryptography_9e2405fed34048fcbe4e2c9e871e31b6
  Complete output (168 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/_oid.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/certificate_transparency.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/ocsp.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/x509
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/poly1305.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_asymmetric.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_cipheralgorithm.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_serialization.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/aead.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ed25519.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ed448.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/poly1305.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x25519.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x448.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed25519.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed448.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/types.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x448.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/aead.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/pkcs12.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/pkcs7.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/ssh.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  running egg_info
  writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.github'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'mypy.ini'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.d'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.playbooks'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.APACHE'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.BSD'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
  writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying src/cryptography/py.typed -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography
  creating build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/asn1.pyi -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/ocsp.pyi -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust/x509.pyi -> build/lib.cygwin-3.3.3-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust
  running build_ext
  running build_rust

      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
      If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
      successfully install cryptography:
      1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
         users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
      2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/ for specific
         instructions for your platform.
      3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq/
      4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
         https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#rust

      Python: 3.8.12
      platform: CYGWIN_NT-10.0-22000-3.3.3-341.x86_64-x86_64-64bit-WindowsPE
      pip: n/a
      setuptools: 59.7.0
      setuptools_rust: 1.1.2
      =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================

  error: can't find Rust compiler

  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

  To update pip, run:

      pip install --upgrade pip

  and then retry package installation.

  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.

  This package requires Rust >=1.41.0.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I didn't find Rust compiler in Cygwin packages and don't want to build it from sources. So I want to figure out why installed cryptography package is not recognized by pip.

Comment: 3.3.2 is the last `cryptography` version that does not require `rust` that is not available on Cygwin. What is the content of `./requirements.txt` ?

Comment: Thanks @matzeri for the hint! `requirements.txt` had only `fabric3` dependency. I added `cryptography==3.3.2` and it works fine now. Please add an answer to mark it as solution.

Comment: Nice. PS: there should be no `pip` but only `pip3` (or old pip2) command on cygwin. From where is it coming from ?

Comment: @matzeri, it is from virtualenv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3.3.2 is the last `cryptography` version that does not require `rust`. So the last possible and available on Cygwin that has no `rust` compiler.

As it seems that `pip` is trying to install the latest upstream release of `cryptography`, forcing the `cryptography==3.3.2` on the requirement should work.

Answer (score -2):

Try to upgrade pip: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: it is up to date: Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (21.3.1)